# flutter - update TextField/TextEditingController via state (provider/consumer)

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a TextField on a "page".  i have a TextEditingController hooked to it.  I can successfully set the value of the TextField via something easy like:

```
usernameController.text = '1234';
```

however, i need to be able to change this field from a child page.  the use case is a login form where the user logs out from inside the app.  when i return to the login page, i want the username/password to be wiped out/deleted.  right now, the values are still there (showing whatever is currently in usernameController.text)

overall, i'm managing state via Provider.  i can set and retrieve/display state in other places in my app with no problem.  the issue becomes that the controller is setup via dart code in initState().  it is not part of a widget that gets rebuilt.

i can setup the TextField widget within a consumer.  the builder gets called when state is updated in the child page (confirmed with the debug print statement) but the widget itself does not reflect the new value of the state (it still has the old username and it is not blanked out).

```
                            Consumer<myAppState>(
                          builder: (context, appState, child) {
                            print("in builder for consumer: ");
                            print(appState.username);
                            return Container(
                                width: 200,
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: usernameController,
                                  onChanged: (value) => _saveUsername(value),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Username',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                                  ),
                                ));
                          }),
```

I've tried replacing

```
usernameController.text = '1234';
```

with:

```
usernameController.text = Provider.of<myAppState>(context, listen: true).username;
```

but that does not seem to work.

it seems this "non-pure" widget (because of the controller being handled programatically) doesn't sit pretty within the Consumer model which wants to redraw widgets.

anyone have any thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: Where are you trying to do `usernameController.text = Provider.of<myAppState>(context, listen: true).username;`

Comment: @HemanthRaj - i have tried making that call inside initState(), so that it gets executed as soon as the "login" page loads.  i haven't seen anywhere in the documentation that "listen: true" actually creates any type of listener that gets notified when notifyListeners() gets called.  i was just trying a "shot in the dark" there adapting code i have seen elsewhere.

Comment: Adding in `initState` would not do the trick. You need to update the value in the `builder` probably.

Comment: @HemanthRaj - i believe i tried that (setting usernameController.text = Provider.of<myAppState>(context, listen: true).username;) in the Consumer's builder and it was throwing an exception because it was "setting a flag to redraw a widget while a redraw was already happening" or something along those lines.  i forget the exact terminology, but i can look it up if that helps.

Comment: my comment about the "redraw" error happened when i tried using setState() inside of builder().  if i try to do a direct assignment of usernameController.text it does not throw and error, but the assignment doesnt seem to take place.  see comments on your suggested answer for more details.  thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible way is to check make a check in the builder if the value in state and controller matches and sync them.

Example:

```
Consumer<myAppState>(
  builder: (context, appState, child) {
    print("in builder for consumer: ");
    print(appState.username);
    if (usernameController.text != appState.username) { // Or check if appState.username != null or what ever your use case is.
      usernameController.text = appState.username ?? '';
    }
    return Container(
      width: 200,
      child: TextField(
        controller: usernameController,
        onChanged: (value) => _saveUsername(value),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Username',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `Consumer<myAppState>(
  builder: (context, appState, child) {
   print("in builder for consumer: ");
   print(appState.username);
   print(usernameController.text);
   usernameController.text = appState.username;
   print('controller after reassignment:');
   print(usernameController.text);
   return Container(
       width: 200,
       child: TextField(
          controller: usernameController,
          onChanged: (value) => _saveUsername(value),
        ));
  })`

returns
...: in builder for consumer: 
...: null
...: 1234
...: controller after reassignment:
...: 1234

Comment: i tried copying and pasting the code/results above but it's ugly.  for the print/debug results i'm getting...
I/flutter (23797): in builder for consumer: 
I/flutter (23797): null
I/flutter (23797): 1234
I/flutter (23797): controller after reassignment:
I/flutter (23797): 1234

so you can see that appState.username is null, usernameController.text is initially '1234', and even after i try to reassign usernameController to the value of appState.username, it ignores that reassignment and still shows '1234'.  maybe trying to assign it to NULL is a problem?

Comment: ok, the problem has to do with how i was setting state in my logout process.  

i was setting to NULL...
    Provider.of<myAppState>(context, listen: false).username = null;

but that wasn't working (as seen in my debugging statements above).  
i switched it to:
    Provider.of<myAppState>(context, listen: false).username = '';

and now it works fine.  

any idea why setting it to null prevented it from working (and it didn't throw any errors)?  it makes sense you cant set a text controller to NULL, but it should generate some error if you try right?

Comment: No, actually. `usernameController.text = appState.username ?? '';` this piece of . code actually makes a null check and assigns empty string if value is . `null`

Comment: gotcha, yeah that would solve the problem too (allow you to set state to NULL but still have UI reflect blank string).  good extra bonus solution!

Comment: i am now seeing "Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." in my logs.  any thoughts?

Comment: note, if i put it in a delay/timer inside builder(), the errors go away.  
ex: Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () => usernameController.text = appState.username);

thoughts?

Comment: `usernameController.text = appState.username ?? '';` triggers an exception. This solution MUST not be marked as accepted, since it's hack and it's not a good practice

Answer (score 1):

As other comments have described:

Setting a `ChangeNotifier` attribute to `null` and calling `NotifyListeners()` such as that of a `TextEditingController` text value will not update statements checking for `null`